# Subrelation in RDB

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

In a typical RDB, I can describe relation with foreign key. However, I am not sure how I can efficiently describe relations within a group. I know it is hard to understand so let me describe this scenario.

I want to make a Gradebook service, where teachers can register and create classes, and students can register and enroll in classes.

```
CREATE TABLE teachers (
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(255),
   ...
)

CREATE TABLE students (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE classes (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  teacher_id BIGINT REFERENCES teachers(id)
)

CREATE TABLE enrollments (
  student_id BIGINT REFERENCES students(id),
  class_id BIGINT REFERENCES classes(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id, class_id)
)
```

In each class, teacher can create assignments, and each student will receive score for the assignments.

```
CREATE TABLE assignments (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  class_id BIGINT REFERENCES class(id)
  ...
)
```

Now, I would describe a score to belong to a student, and to an assignment with foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE scores (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  score INT,
  student_id BIGINT REFERENCES student(id),
  assignment_id BIGINT REFERENCES assignments(id)
)
```

However, there is nothing to stop me from creating a score for a student who does not attend this class. In other words, a score must be accompanied by a corresponding enrollment (same student id). The reason I said this is subrelation is because the relations for score should be scoped locally within a class.

How can I enforce such restriction with RDB?

**UPDATE**:

Based on the suggestion by @Joel Brown, this is what I came up with.

```
CREATE TABLE enrollments (
  class_id BIGINT REFERENCES classes(id),
  student_id BIGINT REFERENCES students(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (class_id, student_id)
);

CREATE TABLE assignments (
  id BIGSERIAL,
  class_id BIGINT REFERENCES classes(id),
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  max_possible_score INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, class_id)
);

CREATE TABLE scores (
  class_id BIGINT,
  student_id BIGINT,
  assignment_id BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (assignment_id, class_id, student_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (class_id, student_id) REFERENCES enrollments(class_id, student_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (assignment_id, class_id) REFERENCES assignments(id, class_id)
);
```

Comment: your assignments should really be to students, not for classes

Comment: but that would mean I have to create the same assignment multiple times, no?

Comment: Not to mention if you have new students in the middle of the class session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that a student cannot get a `SCORE` on an assignment for a class in which they are not enrolled, you have two options:

1. Use application logic
2. Use declarative referential integrity

Some people might argue that the data model you have now works just fine but it will require some application logic to perform a sanity check on the creation of a `SCORE` to ensure that the student ought to have that score.

If you want to ensure that this cannot happen without using application logic, then you have to change your data model.  Your current data model looks like this:

[image: Current ERD]

You can change your data model to look like this instead:
[image: Alternative ERD]

Note the following:

- The `Assignment` is partially identified by its foreign key to the `CLASS`.  This pulls the Class ID down to the assignment so that it will be referenced in turn by `SCORE` in its primary key.
- The `SCORE` is related directly to `ENROLLMENT` rather than to `STUDENT` directly.  This makes sense because the enrollment is the record of a student belonging to a class - so it more closely models the business rule that you are concerned about imposing.
- The primary key of `SCORE` is comprised of its foreign keys to `ENROLLMENT` (which includes Student ID) and `ASSIGNMENT` (which includes Class ID).
- This means that the primary key of `SCORE` will be the combination of class, assignment and student.

If you make sure that you only keep one copy of class ID in your `SCORE` table, then it won't be possible for a student to get a score on an assignment unless that student is also enrolled in the class for which that assignment was given.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as first to address the issue stated in the question. However, you see that you can still create a ***SCORE*** that links to an enrollment for a different class.

Comment: Oh, I just read your explanation about the combination of columns for primary key for SCORE. Let me think about that.

Comment: I just updated my question, let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: @Khanetor - Yes, that's it.